# How should uncertainties be treated when using MinMaxScaler

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset that I am working on to perform some task.

For my brief background, I am using Bayesian statistics to try and constrain some parameter outputs. Whilst the details of this are irrelevant, I have to define a parameter range (prior) over which to perform my search for these 'best-fit' parameters.

This is not an issue at all and this is all working fine, however, I am performing this action on a very large and somewhat 'diverse' dataset. This meaning that the parameter range I have to define for each input file in my dataset is different, based on the data itself. I could probably do something by defining a parameter range for each file such that it lies between minimum and maximum results but some parameters lie outside the scope of this range (an extrapolation per say).

So, to optimise my results and ensure that I get sensible outputs, I believe it is necessary to scale my data to have all the same range so I can define a fixed parameter range e.g. if I scale my data between 0 and 1 then I can fairly reasonably assume that a prior of 0-2 perhaps will encompass my 'best' parameters.

I'm looking at `MinMaxScaler` from `sklearn` to scale my data and scaling this and also inverse scaling this so the original values are returned after my analysis is no issue. However, what I have been unable to find any information about, regarding scaling in general, is how to treat uncertainties.

In other words,I use both my data and uncertainties to perform a chi-squared like analysis and so I need to preserve the relationship between both data and errors such that for my scaled data, this output of this step isn't affected and when I revert the scaled data and errors at the end of my analysis, they represent the outputs I would have got if I hadn't scaled.

Again, while scaling and inverting my data using `MinMaxScaler` is no issue, I am unable to find any information on how uncertainties should be treated for scaling (in general). Most of what I've read just refers to scaling data but no mention of the error scaling. Applying `MinMaxScaler` to the uncertainties for the same range wouldn't work as it would take them as independent to the data and just scale them between 0 and 1 regardless of their relationship to the data (this is my understanding but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong or have missed something).

Also, I am unsure about just multiplying the errors by the scaling factor i.e. returned from `scaler.scale_[0]`, if `scaler = MinMaxScaler()` as this is the relative scaling and wouldn't give information on each individual data point.

If anyone has any insight or knows any resources or advice on how to approach this kind of challenge, I would most grateful.

Thank you